# Prove that $f$ is convex in an interval given an inequality with determinant

Tags: analysis

Today,I found a interesting problem:

> if 
>   $$\begin{vmatrix}
> \cos{x}&\sin{x}&f(x)\\
> \cos{y}&\sin{y}&f(y)\\
> \cos{z}&\sin{z}&f(z)
> \end{vmatrix}\ge 0$$
>   for all $x,y,z$ of an open interval $I$ for which $x<y<z<x+\pi$.
>
> show that:
>   $f(x)$ is convex on $I$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I want know who downvote too?

Comment: @copper.hat I didn't downvote but it pretty much is PSQ.

Comment: @dustin What is PSQ?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke problem statement question. No work shown.

Comment: @dustin Thank you! I was afraid, that something worse, as PMS. :-)

Comment: I found this reslut is simaler with:Schur inequality:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality

Comment: Hello,robjohn,$F$ is RHS,

Comment: @robjohn: I think $F$ is irrelevant here.

Comment: To state that the determinant of the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & x & f(x) \\ 1 & y & f(y) \\ 1 & z & f(z)\end{array}\right)$$ is non-negative for $x<y<z$ is the same as stating that $f$ is convex. I think we have just to manipulate the determinant and use some substitutions.

Comment: or I delete this $F$

Comment: Hello,@JackD'Aurizio,why $f$ is convex?

Comment: @math110: The determinant in Jack's comment is  $f(x)(z-y)+f(y)(x-z)+f(z)(y-x)$ which gives exactly the convexity condition.

Comment: That is a neat identity, I have never seen it before.

Comment: I also can't seen before,can you someone can take some link to explain convexity condition?

Comment: @math110: it is equivalent to:$$\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}\geq\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}.$$ In the matrix, replace the third row with the difference between the third and second row, the second row with the difference between the second row and the first, then expand the determinant with respect to the first column. What kind of inequality do we get from applying the same procedure to the matrix in the original question?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,oh,I know it,+1 ,Thank you

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Bleh! I was just writing up an answer showing convexity, but now I see it has already been discussed in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\le f(x)\sin(z-y)-f(y)\sin(z-x)+f(z)\sin(y-x)\\
&=(f(z)-f(y))\sin(y-x)+f(y)\sin(y-x)(1-\cos(z-y))\\
&-(f(y)-f(x))\sin(z-y)+f(y)\sin(z-y)(1-\cos(y-x))\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Divide by $(z-y)(y-x)$ and take the double limit $\liminf\limits_{x\to y^-}\liminf\limits_{z\to y^+}$
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\le\lim_{x\to y^-}\liminf_{z\to y^+}\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}\frac{\sin(y-x)}{y-x}\\
&+\lim_{x\to y^-}\lim_{z\to y^+}f(y)\frac{\sin(y-x)}{y-x}\frac{1-\cos(z-y)}{z-y}\\
&+\lim_{x\to y^-}\lim_{z\to y^+}f(y)\frac{\sin(z-y)}{z-y}\frac{1-\cos(y-x)}{y-x}\\
&-\limsup\limits_{x\to y^-}\lim_{z\to y^+}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\frac{\sin(z-y)}{z-y}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
which becomes
$$
\limsup\limits_{x\to y^-}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le\liminf_{z\to y^+}\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}\tag{3}
$$
Inequality $(3)$ implies that $f$ is convex. The rest follows from convexity.

Comment: Nice !+1 Thank you very much,if we have convex,Then I can solve it

Comment: Hello, we can also show this $f$ is convex,if $$f(x)\cos{(z-y)}+f(y)\cos{(x-z)}+f(z)\cos{(y-x)}>0$$

Comment: No. That doesn't work. For $x,y,z$ close together, this inequality is satisfied for any positive $f$.